# Stalled Resque Worker Monitoring on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, resque

I am using Resque on Heroku with Heroku Redis. Occasionally and intermittently, the Resque workers are stalling. There are no errors; the workers just don't do anything (it seems). Restarting the dynos fixes the issue.

At the moment, I am less concerned about fixing the root cause of the issue, and more interested in setting up some kind of **monitoring** that will catch these issues. My Google skills are failing me on the topic.

**What are the recommended tools and/or approaches for monitoring Resque Workers and alerting me if they are stalled?**

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular ones is `god` https://github.com/mojombo/god resque even has a wiki mention about it.
The other one is `monit`, but personally I have only had experience with `god`. They provide strong documentation where what you are looking for (notification for problematic workers) is described.
 http://godrb.com/
Look for `NOTIFICATIONS` on the doc page.
Hope this helps and puts you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with God and Monit, but I don't believe they play nicely with Heroku. Am I mistaken?